# Free drawing with FabricJS

Tags: fabricjs

Is it possible to have all the free drawing items put into one layer using the fabric.js api? I have a UI for managing layers (moving up and down layers) but if someone draws a lot in free drawing mode the amount of layers will be huge and the UI won't look great.

A group seems to keep them all in their separate layers. I need to effectively flatten the free drawing to one layer.

Thank you

Comment: Nothing like this built-in, but you should be able to group (all free-drawn paths) after free drawing is done.

Comment: Do you have anything in the api to get the number of groups e.g. canvas.forEachObject for objects?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: My layering algorithm works with jquery ui and the items on the canvas, so if a layer is moved up i know which item to reference on the canvas by the position in the ui. In order to keep that working with groups i would need to be able to access groups as layers like items. So i could know there are e.g. 3 groups and a ui element represent each group rather than each item. Is that possible?

Comment: If you group 3 objects (e.g. 3 free-drawn paths) using `fabric.Group`, then you can work with this group as one object. You can add any number of such groups onto canvas and work with each one individually (moving up/down in z-index, position, etc.)